# English toponymy of ‘Wardle’ in Lancashire (near Rochdale) and ‘Wardle’ in Cheshire (near Nantwich)

Tags: english, etymology

I found on internet that the name of these two places comes from Old English ‘weard’ (watch) and ‘hyll’ (hill).
‘Wardle’  is recorded in the Domesday Book of 1086 as ‘Warhelle’ and as ‘Wardhul’ in 1278,  appears as ‘Wardhill’ in the Assize Court Rolls of the county of 1218 and is also spelled ‘Wordul’ and ‘Wardul’ in the Coucher Book of Whalley Abbey. What is a the detailed linguistic explication of this evolution ?
(I’m not a linguist and english is not my native langage).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking for. What do you want beyond what is given in the etymologies you quoted?

Comment: Thank you. ‘weard’ and ‘hyll’ are local Old English pre 7th century words (‘ard’ can mean high or height in Irish, Scots, Gaelic ?) and I can easy understand that ‘Weard hyll’ became‘Wardhill’ and so on...
But what about ‘wardul’ ? On some roman insciption in Britain you can read similar latin words ie. ‘vardul’ (an abbreviation of ‘vardulli’/’vardullorum’)… See for ex. https://romaninscriptionsofbritain.org/imggal/RIB001272.png Is it possible that ‘wardul’ comes not from Old English but from latin ?

Comment: @Edd I've converted that information to a comment for now, but I recommend editing it into the question itself. You can do that with the "edit" link in the bottom left of the post.